mvn command thrown cannot find symbol builder() error after upgrading to spring boot 3
Recently, I upgraded my team's project from Spring Boot 2.x.x to Spring Boot 3. After updating my Maven pom file and making the necessary code changes (such as switching to Jakarta and updating webSecurity), I encountered a "cannot find symbol" error when running mvn dependency:analyze.
cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   method builder()
...

It seems that everything related to Lombok is not working. I conducted my own research on Stack Overflow and consulted LLMs, but neither source could help me resolve the issue. My pom is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">  <artifactId>whatever-api</artifactId>
  <build>
    <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.14</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0.1746</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <output>file</output>
          <append>true</append>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>jacoco-site-mvn-package</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
        <artifactId>fabric8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.37</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>fmp</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>resource</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>17</source>
          <target>17</target>
          <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
              <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
              <version>1.18.26</version>
            </path>
          </annotationProcessorPaths>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
      <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
      <artifactId>redisson</artifactId>
      <version>3.17.1</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>netty-codec</artifactId>
          <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
          <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
      <artifactId>redisson-spring-data-24</artifactId>
      <version>3.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
      <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
      <version>6.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
      <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.2</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
      <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.34.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
      <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.83</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.alibaba.fastjson2</groupId>
      <artifactId>fastjson2</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.33</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-context</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.6</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-internal.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-fabric8-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
      <artifactId>kubernetes-client</artifactId>
      <version>4.13.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
      <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
      <version>4.10.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.squareup.okio</groupId>
          <artifactId>okio-jvm</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.squareup.okio</groupId>
      <artifactId>okio</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.j2objc</groupId>
      <artifactId>j2objc-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
          <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.11</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
          <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-vault-config</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <version>1.6.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
      <version>21.1.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-spanner-jdbc</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
          <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
          <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>grpc-netty-shaded</artifactId>
          <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
      <version>5.6.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <version>3.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.4</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <version>3.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>checkout-sdk</artifactId>
      <groupId>com.paypal.sdk</groupId>
      <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
      <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>json</artifactId>
      <version>20231013</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
      <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
      <version>${netty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
      <artifactId>netty-codec</artifactId>
      <version>${netty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
      <artifactId>grpc-okhttp</artifactId>
      <version>1.58.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
      <artifactId>grpc-netty</artifactId>
      <version>1.33.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.librepdf</groupId>
      <artifactId>openpdf</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.27</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.librepdf</groupId>
      <artifactId>openpdf-fonts-extra</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.27</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>10.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
      <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
      <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
      <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
      <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>msdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>definitions</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>msdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>jpmc-msdk</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>msdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>MSDKCodeAssist</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.core5</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpcore5</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <version>1.18.26</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
      <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
      <version>1.70</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>32.0.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.xerial.snappy</groupId>
      <artifactId>snappy-java</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.10.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ede</groupId>
      <artifactId>encrypt</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
      <version>1.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
      <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.29</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.8.RELEASE</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-stream-binder</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-storage</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.8.RELEASE</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
          <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
          <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.braintreepayments.gateway</groupId>
      <artifactId>braintree-java</artifactId>
      <version>3.11.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
      <version>0.1.54</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.javacrumbs.shedlock</groupId>
      <artifactId>shedlock-spring</artifactId>
      <version>4.34.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.internal</groupId>
      <artifactId>internal-library</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
          <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
          <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>grpc-netty-shaded</artifactId>
          <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>google-cloud-pubsub</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
          <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.javacrumbs.shedlock</groupId>
      <artifactId>shedlock-provider-jdbc-template</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>cn.hutool</groupId>
      <artifactId>hutool-all</artifactId>
      <version>5.8.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
      <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
      <version>1.57.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sendgrid</groupId>
      <artifactId>sendgrid-java</artifactId>
      <version>4.6.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jexcelapi</groupId>
      <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
          <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
      <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
      <artifactId>simpleclient_common</artifactId>
      <version>0.16.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-spanner</artifactId>
      <version>6.12.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.api.grpc</groupId>
      <artifactId>proto-google-cloud-spanner-v1</artifactId>
      <version>6.12.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.api</groupId>
      <artifactId>gax</artifactId>
      <version>2.23.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.api</groupId>
      <artifactId>gax-grpc</artifactId>
      <version>2.20.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
      <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
      <version>1.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
        <version>26.29.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <description>Payment gateway for all payment services.</description>
  <groupId>com.internal</groupId>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <name>PaymentServices</name>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <relativePath/>
    <version>3.2.11</version> 
  </parent>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <id>local</id>
      <properties>
        <springProfile>local, disableVault</springProfile>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <id>lde</id>
      <properties>
        <springProfile>lde, disableVault</springProfile>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <id>vault</id>
      <properties>
        <springProfile>vault</springProfile>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <properties>
    <tomcat.version>9.0.69</tomcat.version>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    <spring.core.version>6.1.14</spring.core.version>
    <spring-internal.version>3.2.12</spring-internal.version>
    <spring-security.version>6.2.2</spring-security.version>
    <jacoco.version>0.8.10</jacoco.version>
    <prometheus.version>0.16.0</prometheus.version>
    <jackson.version>2.16.1</jackson.version>
    <netty.version>4.2.0.Alpha1</netty.version>
    <sonar.coverage.exclusions>
      **/exception/**,
      **/example/**,
      **/test/*
      **/configuration/**,
      **/entity/**,
      **/enums/**,
      **/payload/**,
      **/model/**,
      **/dao/**,
      **/aop/**,
      **/constant/**,
      **/converter/**,
      **/monitor/**,
      **/repository/**,
      **/response/**,
      **/response/**,
      **/example/**,
      **/uid_generator/**,
      **/mock/**,
      **/oracleentity/**,
      **/scheduler/**,
      **/constant/**,
      **/constants/**,
      **/exception/**,
      **/message/**/*,
      **/statistics/**,
      **/security/**,
      **/configuration/**,
      **/property/**,
      **/specification/**,
      **/dailysyncreport/**,
      **/giftcard/**
    </sonar.coverage.exclusions>
  </properties>
  <version>2.4.0</version>
</project>


[mre], please. If you already suspect lombok, 90% of you pom.xml can go.

Your dependencies are a mess, they contain incompatible versions, you are managing way to much dependencies manually instead of using the Spring Boot dependency management. So for starters stop using versions for the Spring Boot starters (they are managed by the parent) as well as the spring boot maven plugin. You are also using Spring Cloud that is also tied to certain Spring Boot versions and should be compatible, yours largely aren't.

You has lombok dependency as optional:
<dependency>
  <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
  <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
  <version>1.18.26</version>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>

Just delete optional and it'll be ok
